How can I create different apps with the same solution in .NET MAUI?
I've been seeing that in Xamarin you can create different applications (or versions) on Android with the same solution, just by changing the AndoridManifest, setting conditions #if and creating new solution configurations...
Can the same be done at MAUI? Is there any documentation of this?
Or I have to create another solution and move everything around.
I have an example page but it's in Spanish:
https://rodrigotristany.medium.com/xamarin-build-variants-crear-diferentes-aplicaciones-con-una-misma-soluci%C3%B3n-parte-1-77e83d89b44d

this is generally called "white labeling"

@Jason But there's some guide or something?

Can the same be done at MAUI? Is there any documentation of this? Or do I have to create another solution and move everything around.
Yes and you can literally copy paste it to make it work

The method described in the document you provided is also supported in the Maui project: Build -> Configuration Manager -> Active solution configuration

You can define the version of the .NET MAUI project in .csproj file：
<ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0<ApplicationDisplayVersion>
<ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

In this way, version management can be achieved
